# Show box on mousehover

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tooltip, mouseover, force-layout

I am beginning with d3.js and I would like to know the simplest way to show a box containing text (a tooltip) when my the mouse is over a node of my force-directed graph. Moreover, the text contained in this box must be custom for each node (something like `function(d){return d.fullName;})`)

Here is a sample code of what I have for now.

```
var node = vis.selectAll("g.node")
    .data(json.nodes)
    .enter().append("svg:g")
    .attr("class", "node"); 

node.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 12)
    .style("fill", "orange");
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [D3: show data on mouseover of circle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805184/d3-show-data-on-mouseover-of-circle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By box, do you mean a tooltip? In Mike's examples, he uses this idiom:

```
node.append("title")
    .text(function(d) { return d.fullName: });
```

(With other types of elements (`div`s only?) you can just use `element.setAttribute("title", "title");`.)