# d3js tooltip click event not working in ios chrome browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, d3.js

I have a d3js linechart with tooltip, the click event on d3js circle(d3js node) is not working in ios chrome, but it is working fine in ios safari.

Comment: Here is the example plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZFnnFdDU8NcFDCIW779d?p=preview

Comment: I observed that it is because of the getScreenCTM() method that I used. I used that to position my tooltip on exact node position. I followed this answer as reference for that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16256454/d3-js-position-tooltips-using-element-position-not-mouse-position