# How to import d3.event as submodule into react app to use d3.event.pageX

Tags: javascript, d3.js, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

Our react app uses d3 heavily, and we used to import all of d3 into our app using `import * as d3 from 'd3'`. To make our bundle smaller, we are replacing these with submodule imports such as `import { select } from 'd3-selection'`. However, we are struggling with importing `d3.event` in order to use `d3.event.pageX`:

Here is a snippet of our code:

```
.on('mouseover', function (d) {
    // console.log('d: ', d);
    // Tooltip Display + Position + Colors
    tipDiv.transition().duration(0).style('opacity', 1);
    tipDiv.html(tipHtml(d, tooltipName))
        .style('left', (d3.event.pageX - 10) + 'px')
        .style('top', (d3.event.pageY + 35) + 'px');
    tipDiv
        .style('background', colorScale(d.netFgPct7Hex))
        .style('color', whiteBlack(colorScale(d.netFgPct7Hex), 'rgb'));
```

This throws the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'pageX' of undefined` which makes sense, because by removing the `import * as d3 from 'd3'`, we're no longer importing d3.event. It doesn't seem like there is a separate `d3-event` module, and using: `import { event} from 'd3-selection'` doesn't work either, returning `Attempted import error: 'event' is not exported from 'd3-selection'.`

What submodule / how can we import and use d3.event then?

**Edit:** I'm looking into d3.pointer, and maybe d3.event.pageX is not needed per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16256454/d3-js-position-tooltips-using-element-position-not-mouse-position)

Comment: For D3v6 , d3.event has been removed, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63693132/7106086).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to get node datum on mouseover in D3 v6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63693132/unable-to-get-node-datum-on-mouseover-in-d3-v6) - this comment is autogenerated by SO when you flag something as duplicate