# d3js tooltip is positioned incorrectly on bootstrap web

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, d3.js, tooltip

I have been trying to implement treemap graph from d3.js lib on my free time project and I struggle to position the tooltip correctly. I assume it's should be as mentioned [here](https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/heatmap_tooltip.html), but with a few more divs I guess it is misplaced. This is the [treemap](https://github.com/ArmanFeyzi/Treemap-chart) I am using, I tried some suggestions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16256454/d3-js-position-tooltips-using-element-position-not-mouse-position) but none seem to make it work for my usage.

Here is my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lucas03/5q0v2mf9/4/):

```
.on("mousemove", function (d) {
        // console.log(d)
        tooltip.transition()
          .duration(300)
          .style("opacity", .98);
        tooltip.html(`<div class="tooltip-body" data-id=${d.data.name} >
          Symbol: ${d.data.name}<br/>
          Value: ${d.data.current_value} USD<br/>
          Change: ${d.data.pc}%<br/></div>`)
           .style("left", d3.mouse(this)[0] + "px")
           .style("top", d3.mouse(this)[1] + "px")
      })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the coordinates. Replace `d3.mouse` with `d3.event`:

```
.on("mousemove", function (d) {
  ...     
  tooltip.html(`<div class="tooltip-body" data-id=${d.data.name} >
    Symbol: ${d.data.name}<br/>
    Value: ${d.data.current_value} USD<br/>
    Change: ${d.data.pc}%<br/></div>`)
    .style("left", d3.event.offsetX + "px")
    .style("top", d3.event.offsetY + "px")
 })
```

Comment: thanks, that is better. But on firefox it flashes on top left position randomly  - https://monosnap.com/file/H9fzI9zfVCR3fMMLbPgD8ia3guln7K

Comment: seems like it has wrong position when I mouseover text, when I mouseover box it's redered correctly

Comment: here is gif of how it shows in firefox - https://monosnap.com/file/u6OPu4agP5UypE3jqFXY29GJOe5HXo

Comment: Replace offsetX / offsetY with layerX / layerY. Does it help with Firefox?

Comment: it does indeed. Thanks you!