# Problem to show dynamic text on mouseover in D3.js and json file?

Tags: d3.js

I am brand new to the d3 and I try to display a text included in a json file on circle in d3.

Comment: It would be better if you posted your code in your answer rather than linking to it. I was going to edit it in myself, but it seemed like I had to make an account somewhere to get at it...

Comment: Do you want a tooltip? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805184/d3-show-data-on-mouseover-of-circle/10806220

Answer (score 0):

```
svg.selectAll("circle")
.data( theData ).enter()
.append("circle")
.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
.attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
.attr("r", theCircleRadius);

svg.selectAll("text.server")
.data( theData ).enter()
.append("text")
.attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
.attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; })
.style("text-anchor", "middle");
```