# How to display node title in d3 forced-collapsible?

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I am implementing the forced-collapsible given here: http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111116/force-collapsible.html

[image]

How can I display the node-title for a node when I hover the cursor over that node. Please help.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805184/d3-show-data-on-mouseover-of-circle/10806220#10806220) should help.

Comment: Lars: Thanks! One more thing, instead of hover, if a want to display the node-title on clicking the node, how that can be done? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: That case is a bit more complicated as it's not a standard tooltip. You'll have to attach an event handler to the `click` event that will make something like a floating `div` visible.