# How to add ToolTip to D3 Tree node?

Tags: html, json, d3.js

I have D3 Tree like this:

http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/tree.html

How can I add description i.e. ToolTip to each node so that if use hover any node the tooltip will be visible (assuming tooltip will come from json)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to display name of node when mouse over on node in collapsible tree graph](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19297808/how-to-display-name-of-node-when-mouse-over-on-node-in-collapsible-tree-graph)

Comment: Also possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805184/d3-show-data-on-mouseover-of-circle/10806220#10806220