# d3 - Adding Tooltip to Area Chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, d3.js

I'm trying to add tooltip to a chart in the following link [**Focus+Context via Brushing**](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367). And i was able to add the tooltip using the mouseon and mouseout event from this [**link**](http://www.d3noob.org/2013/01/adding-tooltips-to-d3js-graph.html). But the challenge is i cannot get the value on hovering, only the div is appearing. And the div appearing on all the parts of the area chart. I want to it to be appeared only on the edges while hovering. Someone please help me in this.

Comment: What kind of tooltip are you after specifically? If all you need is a generic one, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805184/d3-show-data-on-mouseover-of-circle/10806220#10806220) should help.

Comment: It reads like you want to display some information off to the side of the chart.  If that's the case you can simply have some text displayed in a div next to your chart.

Comment: I'm looking for a tooltip like the one in this url http://nvd3.org/ghpages/stackedArea.html

Comment: I would suggest you use Path over area chart...I caught up with same problem and i achieved the output by using path over area..

Comment: @sam - Can you share me that tooltip code?

Comment: actually i am out of topic nw.. if you show the example i would help you..

Comment: In this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/henbox/jzPaq/) I have created a chart using path. I want to add a tooltip on hover like we have in this [**link**](http://nvd3.org/examples/stackedArea.html). Would you be able to help me out.