# How to enable tool tip on collapsible tree graph

Tags: d3.js, tooltip

I am developing collapsible tree graph(http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083). i am tried to generate tool tip but i am unable to generate and also i need to show some value that value coming from json  . can any one plz help me how to do .

Comment: Have you seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805184/d3-show-data-on-mouseover-of-circle/10806220)?

Comment: yes i have done..now i want name along with value.i have also define value in json file now i want to return both.

Comment: any one plz help me how to do ?

Comment: @Sumit If you want more help, you'll have to give more information about your data and what you have tried that doesn't work.  The examples Lars linked to set the text of the tooltip based on the data object.  You can use a single data value, or create a string that combines multiple data values.  Something like: `function(d){return d.name + ": " + d.value;});`