# Show texts on Mouseover on links

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to show text on `mouseover` on links, but I am not able to see any text. I only can change the colour like in the code attached below.

Any help with the tool tips is also welcome as I tried that too.

[Here is the code to the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pria_3/70qy8ps6/13/).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pria_3/70qy8ps6/6/  Reference to the code

Comment: link.on("mouseover", function() { d3.select(this).style("stroke","red").text("hello"); });

Comment: You should include the reference to the code in the question.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pria_3/70qy8ps6/13/    Please find the code here.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805184/d3-show-data-on-mouseover-of-circle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way.

```
link.on('mouseover', function(d, i) {
    d3.select(this).style("stroke", "red");
    if (!d3.select("#link-label-" + i).node()) {
        svg.append("text")
            .attr("id", "link-label-" + i)
            .attr("font-family", "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif")
            .attr("x", function() {
                if (d.target.x > d.source.x) {
                    return (d.source.x + (d.target.x - d.source.x) / 2);
                } else {
                    return (d.target.x + (d.source.x - d.target.x) / 2);
                }
            })
            .attr("y", function() {
                if (d.target.y > d.source.y) {
                    return (d.source.y + (d.target.y - d.source.y) / 2);
                } else {
                    return (d.target.y + (d.source.y - d.target.y) / 2);
                }
            })
            .attr("fill", "Black")
            .style("font", "normal 12px Arial")
            .attr("dy", ".35em")
            .text(function() {
                return d.source.name + " - " + d.target.name;
            });
    }
}).on('mouseout', function(d, i) {
    d3.select(this).style("stroke", d.target.group == 2?"black":"#9ecae1");
    d3.select("#link-label-" + i).remove();
});
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/70qy8ps6/15/)

Comment: Thanku so much..It works fine.but if i pass d in text function it gives me an error saying target undefined.

Comment: .text(function(d) {
                   var value  = d.target.data.split(" ");
                   var result = parseInt(value[0]); //I want to show this result on mouseover

Comment: It Worked..I got the error i should not have passed d twice when we are already passing in mouseover function...:)

Answer (score 0):

Since your `circle`s are already bound to data you can do something like this

```
d3.select('circle')
    .attr('title', function(d){
        return d.name; //or whatever
    });
```

an use the default browser tooltip

Comment: No No i want to show the data on link mouseover. for Circle i could do.