# D3 pieChart section label for small area

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I am trying to use `d3.js` pie chart, problem is if the percent is small for some section then the label get cut with section.

[Link](http://jsfiddle.net/qkHK6/1709/)

```
var data = [{"label":"Category A", "value":5}, 
            {"label":"Category B", "value":50}, 
            {"label":"Category C", "value":30}];
```

"Category A" label does not fit in small section. How can I make label visible even if the section is small?

Comment: Suggest you to add tool-tip instead of labels.
[D3 : Data on mousehover](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805184/d3-show-data-on-mouseover-of-circle)

Comment: How about labels with lines: http://bl.ocks.org/dbuezas/9306799?