# D3 binding data to SVG tooltip

Tags: d3.js

Id like to use [this tooltip](http://bl.ocks.org/biovisualize/1016860) from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805184/d3-show-data-on-mouseover-of-circle) however I can't figure out how to bind data to it.

In this example I'd like to have two circles, that on hover show their size value as text.

**watch.csv**

```
circle,size
green,5
yellow,10
```

**code**

```
d3.csv("watch.csv", function(error, watch) {

  var tooltip = d3.select("body")
    .append("div")
    .style("position", "absolute")
    .style("z-index", "10")
    .style("visibility", "hidden")
    .text(function(d) { return d.size; })    //TRYING THIS

  var sampleSVG = d3.select(".example_div")
    .append("svg:svg")
    .attr("class", "sample")
    .attr("width", 300)
    .attr("height", 300);

  d3.select(".example_div svg")
    .data(watch)                  //AND THIS
    .enter()                      
    .append("svg:circle")
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .attr("fill", "aliceblue")
    .attr("r", 30)
    .attr("cx", 52)
    .attr("cy", 52)
    .on("mouseover", function() {
      return tooltip.style("visibility", "visible");
    })
    .on("mousemove", function() {
      return tooltip.style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 10) + "px").style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 10) + "px");
    })
    .on("mouseout", function() {
      return tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");
    });


});
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LAFfsCHSzfl1pL4s2eiU?p=info)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your tooltip `var` for this:

```
var tooltip = d3.select("body")
    .append("div")
    .attr("class", "someTooltip")
    .style("opacity", 0);
```

Style your tooltip in the CSS, using the selector `.someTooltip`.

And change all your "mouseove", "mousemove" and "mouseout" for this:

```
.on("mousemove", function(d) {
     tooltip.html("The size is: " + d.size)
    .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 10) + "px")
    .style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 10) + "px")
    .style("opacity", 1);
}).on("mouseout", function(){
    tooltip.style("opacity", 0);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add jquery and tipsy which is a jquery plugin.

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tipsy/1.0.3/jquery.tipsy.js"></script>
```

tipsy css

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tipsy/1.0.3/jquery.tipsy.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Next you need to bind the data to the tipsy jquery way like this.

```
$('svg circle').tipsy({ //select all circles
    gravity: 'w', 
    html: true, 
    title: function() {
      var d = this.__data__;//get the data from the dom
      return 'Hi there! My color is <span style="color:' + d.circle + '">' + d.size + '</span>'; //make the tipsy tool tip using the data
    }
  });
```

Remove all the tooltip code like this as that is not needed:

```
 .on("mouseover", function() {
      return tooltip.style("visibility", "visible");
    })
    .on("mousemove", function() {
      return tooltip.style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 10) + "px").style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 10) + "px");
    })
    .on("mouseout", function() {
      return tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");
    });
```

Remove this

```
var tooltip = d3.select("body")
    .append("div")
    .style("position", "absolute")
    .style("z-index", "10")
    .style("visibility", "hidden")
    .text(function(d) { return d.size; })    //TRYING THIS
```

So your code will look like this [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/QE3SqtnfJCsGSBXmSfvA?p=preview)