# D3 js line chart with tooltip on hover with multiple line chart

Tags: jquery, angularjs, d3.js

I have tried this linked

http://jsfiddle.net/jasonantho/wmab3tyw/6/

`please help me with more comment lines on code to clearly understand it`

i have finished the multiple line graph but i need to get tooltip with the information data please any one help me on this thanks in advance.

Comment: http://bl.ocks.org/Caged/6476579 this will do what you want!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to append an svg:title element to each circle, as the browser will take care of showing the tooltip and you don't need the mousehandler. The code would be something like

```
vis.selectAll("circle")
   .data(datafiltered).enter().append("svg:circle")
   ...
   .append("svg:title")
   .text(function(d) { return d.x; });
```

If you want fancier tooltips, you could use tipsy for example. See [here](http://bl.ocks.org/ilyabo/1373263) for an example.

This answer was taken from [Show data on mouseover of circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805184/d3-show-data-on-mouseover-of-circle).
I put the same answer here as recomendation :D

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13973168)

Comment: I edited my answer. Tnx a lot for the recomendation :D