# problem with D3 lasso circle element with text

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I basically copied the example https://bl.ocks.org/skokenes/a85800be6d89c76c1ca98493ae777572

Then I got the code to work with my data. So, I can now get the lasso to work.

But when I try to add back my old code for the circles to display a text-type tool tip, the lasso breaks.  The code then puts the class variables such as not_possible or selected on the "text" elements rather than on the "circle" elements where they need to be.

I found that is the issue by using Chrome developer tools.

When the tool tips code is commented out, the lasso code works and the DOM looks like this:

```
<circle cx="854" cy="37" fill="red" r="7" class="selected"></circle>
```

When the tool tips code is live, the tool tips work but the lasso code doesn't work and the DOM looks like this:

```
<circle cx="854" cy="37" fill="red" r="4.9">
  <title  r="3.5" class> ==$0
      "curr = 89.7, prev = 89.5, geo = Alaska, measure = Percent Citizen, Born in the US"
  </title>
</circle>
```

I've tried changing the styles for the classes, for example, from ".possible" to "circle.possible" but that doesn't help. I've googled for suggestions but haven't found anything that I could make work. I've tried passing the circle selection thru lasso.items(circles) but that doesn't work.

This is the lasso code that does work:  the troublesome ".append title" and "text" lines are commented out.

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 15, bottom: 60, left: 60}
   , width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right
   , height = 960 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
         .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d[1]; })])
         .range([0, width]);

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
         .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d[0]; })])
         .range([height, 0]);

var svgArea = d3.select('.content')
         .append('svg')
         .attr('width', width + margin.right + margin.left)
         .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
         .attr('class', 'chart');

var main = svgArea.append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height)
    .attr('class', 'main');   

main.append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
        .attr('class', 'main axis date')
        .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale)); 

main.append('g') 
        .append("text")
        .attr("x", width / 2)      
        .attr("y", height + margin.bottom - 10)
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .style("font", "14px times")
        .text("Current X");

main.append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(0,0)')
        .attr('class', 'main axis date')
        .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale));

main.append('g') 
        .append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("x", 0 - (height / 2))      
        .attr("y", 0 - margin.left / 2)
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .style("font", "14px times")
        .text("Previous Y");

var rScale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d[1]; })])
        .range([ 4, 5 ]);

var lasso_start = function() {
  lasso.items()
    .attr("r",7)                 
    .classed("not_possible",true)
    .classed("selected",false)
    ;
};

var lasso_draw = function() {
  lasso.possibleItems()
    .classed("not_possible",false)
    .classed("possible",true)
    ;

  lasso.notPossibleItems()
    .classed("not_possible",true)
    .classed("possible",false)
    ;
};

var lasso_end = function() {
  lasso.items()
      .classed("not_possible",false)
      .classed("possible",false)
    ;

  lasso.selectedItems()
      .classed("selected",true)
      .attr("r", 7)
    ;

  lasso.notSelectedItems()
      .attr("r", 3.5)
    ;
};

var circles = main.selectAll("circle")
      .data(data)
      .enter().append("circle")
          .attr("cx", function (d,i) { return xScale(d[1]); } )
          .attr("cy", function (d) { return yScale(d[0]); } )
          .attr("fill", function (d) { if (d[1] > 75) { return "red"; } else { return "black"; } }) 
          .attr("r", function (d) { return rScale(d[1]); }) 
          //.append("title")                                  
          //.text(function(d) {
          //      return "curr = " + d[1] +
          //             ", prev = " + d[0] +
          //             ", geo = " + d[2] +
          //             ", measure = " + d[3]; 
          //      }) 
          ;

var lasso = d3.lasso()
      .items(circles)                                     
      .closePathDistance(75) // max distance for the lasso loop to be closed
      .closePathSelect(true) // can items be selected by closing the path?
      .targetArea(svgArea) // area where the lasso can be started
      .on("start",lasso_start) // lasso start function
      .on("draw",lasso_draw) // lasso draw function
      .on("end",lasso_end); // lasso end function

svgArea.call(lasso);
```

Why does including ".title" and ".text" cause a problem?
And how do I solve it?

I don't think the problem is with the CSS, but here it is:

```
<style>
// styling for D3 chart
.chart {
    background: #fdfefe;
}

.main text {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
}

// styling for D3-lasso     

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

circle {
  fill-opacity: 0.4;
}

.dot {
  stroke: #000;
}

.lasso path {
  stroke: rgb(80,80,80);
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

.lasso .drawn {
  fill-opacity: 0.05 ;
}

.lasso .loop_close {
  fill: none;
  stroke-dasharray: 4,4;
}

.lasso .origin {
  fill: #3399FF;
  fill-opacity: 0.5;
}

.not_possible {
  fill: rgb(200,200,200);
}

.possible {
  fill: #EC888C;
}

.selected {
  fill: steelblue;
}


</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be that lasso is adding a radius attribute to the `title` elements here:

```
lasso.notSelectedItems()
      .attr("r", 3.5)
    ;
```

resulting in all your not-selected elements, i.e., `circle`s, and `title`s, having the attribute assigned, as your example suggests:

```
<title  r="3.5" class>
```

Rather than calling lasso's `selected` and `notSelected` to change the radius and css class of the desired items, use a filter on the `items` array itself:

```
  // Style the selected dots
  lasso.items().filter(function(d) {return d.selected===true})
    .classed(...)
    .attr("r",7);

  // Reset the style of the not selected dots
  lasso.items().filter(function(d) {return d.selected===false})
    .classed(...)
    .attr("r",3.5);
```

You can get as specific as you want with the return value, i.e., omit any nodes (like `title` nodes) you don't want affected by the rules you apply to the selection.

Comment: I tried your "lasso.items().filter" suggestion, but I couldn't get it to work:  my code still applied class to title elements rather than to circle elements.   But I found a fix: a workaround that avoids appending titles: Mikhail Shabrikov's code near the bottom of the page about using [mouse events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805184/show-data-on-mouseover-of-circle/)

Comment: Excellent!  I have done similar to that workaround with a 3rd party tooltip (semantic).  I'd have suggested that as well, but we are compelled in this forum to try to answer a specific question as specifically as possible.  As we all know, there's often another way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I couldn't get D3 lasso and my approach to tool tips to work together.  I was appending a title element to each circle (point) on a scatter plot.  This does NOT work:

```
var circles = main.selectAll("circle")
      .data(data)
      .enter().append("circle")
          .attr("cx", function (d,i) { return xScale(d[1]); } )
          .attr("cy", function (d) { return yScale(d[0]); } )
          .attr("fill", function (d) { if (d[1] > 75) { return "red"; } else { return "black"; } })
          .attr("r", function (d) { return rScale(d[1]); })
          .append("title")                                  
          .text(function(d) {
                return "curr = " + d[1] +
                       ", prev = " + d[0] +
                       ", geo = " + d[2] +
                       ", measure = " + d[3]; 
                }) 
          ;
```

I found a coding example by Mikhail Shabrikov that solved the issue by avoiding .append("title") altogether. This works:

A new CSS element:

```
.tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    visibility: hidden;
    background-color: lightblue;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: black;
}
```

A new DIV element:

```
var tooltip = d3.select("body")
  .append("div")
  .attr('class', 'tooltip');
```

And mainly a modified circles element:

```
var circles = main.selectAll("circle")
      .data(data)
      .enter().append("circle")
          .attr("cx", function (d,i) { return xScale(d[1]); } )
          .attr("cy", function (d) { return yScale(d[0]); } )
          .attr("fill", function (d) { if (d[1] > 75) { return "red"; } else { return "black"; } })
          .attr("r", 5)
          .on("mouseover", function(d) {return tooltip.style("visibility", "visible")
               .text(
                         "curr = " + d[1] +
                         ", prev = " + d[0] +
                         ", geo = " + d[2] +
                         ", measure = " + d[3]
                   )
             })
          .on("mousemove", function() {
               return tooltip.style("top", (event.pageY - 30) + "px")
                 .style("left", event.pageX + "px");
             })
          .on("mouseout", function() {
               return tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");
             })
          ;
```

Shabrikov's code is near the very bottom of this item:  [circles, tool tips, mouse events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805184/show-data-on-mouseover-of-circle)